# I can't run my script for a google sheet, how do I verify app?

Tags: google-sheets

My script uses reference cells linked to an external sheet to hide or show rows as I need them. It says I am not an authorized user. I don't own the sheet but am granted editor permissions. It's worked a ton before, I don't know why this is happening now. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to deal with this yet but have you tried something like...

```
function authTest() {
  // Log the URL used to grant access to the script.
  var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);
  Logger.log(authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl());
};
```

More information can be found in [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/authorization-info#getAuthorizationStatus())